# Favicon not working for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, favicon

I am trying to add favicon to mysite but it is not working. I have put my favicon to **C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\expound** folder

Then in **header.php** file, I put the code below:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: what's the return of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`?

Comment: It will return path C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/expound

Comment: then in this case it's likely a permissions issue; you shouldn't be using the full path. Use the relative path to the favicon, and make sure you can browse to it directly in the browser.

Comment: Its a caching issue, try reactivating your theme, switch to another one, then activate you them again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried selecting your site's "icon" in the admin panel? It's a little hard to find, but it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Open your site then customize -> open Site Identity -> Set Site Icon after you can show favicon icon.